# Regex Remove Character Sets From String and Add Them To An Array

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
 original_string = "(black && green) || (red && blue)"
```

I want to pull out all the words and add them to an array.  The result I am looking for would be:

```
vars = ["black", "green", "red", "blue"]
```

So I've been experimenting with regular expressions, and I wrote the following to split the string:

```
vars = re.split('\W+', original_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Which sort of works, but returns the following:

```
vars = [u'', u'black', u'green', u'red', u'blue', u'']
```

So I turned the list items int strings:

```
var_list = []
for var in vars:
    var = str(var)
    var_list.append(var)
```

Which returns:

```
['', 'black', 'green', 'red', 'blue', '']
```

So the array has a count of 6 rather than 4 because of the two ' ' in the array. But I am not sure where the ' ' are coming from or how to get rid of them.

Comment: How did your colors turn into animals?

Comment: oops! i got sloppy with my copy/paste. i'll fix that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> original_string = "(black && green) || (red && blue)"
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', original_string)
['black', 'green', 'red', 'blue']
```